# A question on Trigonometric limits

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

What will this expression $(\cos x)^{\csc x}$ simplify to when $x\rightarrow 0$.
I tried writing $\cos{x}$ as $(1-(1-\cos{x}))$

Comment: Any reason to do it without Lhopital? Typical way to solve these problems is $f^g=e^{glnf}$ then use Lhopital...

Comment: My thought is that it should be 1, because near $0$ cosine looks like 1 + (higher order terms, all less than 1) and you are raising this to some large power. So all the little terms shrink quite rapidly to 0 and you are left with just 1. I don't know how to really prove it though without L'Hospital.

Comment: @frank000 I haven't studied lhopital yet

Comment: Did you see what wolfram alpha says

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I don't know what is that

Comment: wolfram alpha is a computer program that does  advanced math.

Answer (score 1):

[Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) guarantees
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\cos(x)^{\csc(x)}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(1-\sin^2(x)\right)^{\frac1{2\sin(x)}}\\
&\ge\lim_{x\to0}(1-\sin(x))^{1/2}\\[2pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: simplest and shortest possible answer. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thanks. However, $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\cos(x)^{\csc^2(x)}$ might be more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
L=
\log\left(\cos x\right)^{\csc x}=
\csc x\log\cos x=
\frac{\log\cos x}{\sin x}
\to\frac{(\log\cos x)'}{(\sin x)'}=
\frac{\frac{-\sin x}{\cos x}}{\cos x}
\to0
$$
by [L'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule), and therefore
$$\left(\cos x\right)^{\csc x}=e^L\to e^0=1$$
as $x\to0$.
If we're dead set against using L'Hopital's Rule,
then we can expand some Taylor (or Maclaurin) series:
$$\begin{align}L&=\log\left(\cos x\right)^{\csc x}\\
&=\csc x\cdot\log\cos x\\
&=\left(\frac1x+\tfrac16x+\tfrac7{360}x^3+\cdots\right)
\left(-\tfrac12x^2-\tfrac1{12}x^4-\tfrac1{45}x^6+\cdots\right)\\
&=-\left(\tfrac12x+\tfrac16x^3+\tfrac{11}{240}x^5+\tfrac{11}{840}x^7+\cdots\right)
\end{align}
$$
which will also clearly approach $0$ as $x$ does,
since the constant term is $0$.

Comment: OP says without Lhopital in the tag...

Comment: @frank000 Thanks, I didn't notice the tag.

Answer (score 0):

$y = \lim_\limits{x\to0} (\cos x)^{\csc x}\\
\ln y = \lim_\limits{x\to0} \frac{\ln(\cos x)}{sin x}$

Now I generally avoid L'Hopital's rule. But, this would be an ideal time to use it.

$\ln y = \lim_\limits{x\to0} \frac{\tan x)}{cos x} = 0$
$y = 1$

However, you have tagged this "limits without L'Hopitals" I will do my best.

when $0.5<x<1.5, |\ln x| < |1-x^2|$

$|\ln(\cos x)| < 1-\cos^2 x = \sin^2 x$ when $|x|<|\pi/3|$

$|\ln y| < |\lim_\limits{x\to0} \sin x|$

And $\ln y$ gets squeezed to 0.